# Animations on pushpins Bing Map Control

Tags: c#, animation, uwp, maps

Hello I am working on UWP map based application. I want to provide  a path animation to my pushpin the way demonstrated in the Bing Maps documentation [here](https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2014/09/25/part-2-bring-your-maps-to-life-creating-animations-with-bing-maps-net/) .

### The Issue is

I can't use the bing map SDK as I can not use any other Tile source (like OSM) except for bing and neither can I remove the copyright information.

---

Anyone can help me with creating path animations a pushpin on the XAML map control? which is provided by default in the Controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't use the bing map SDK

Bing Map SDK is used for previous versions, in UWP app we have [MapControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.aspx) instead. And the animations you mentioned are not provided by SDK, they are just [animations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/animations-overview) in UWP app. So actually you don't need use the Bing Map SDK as what you want has no relationships with the SDK.

> Anyone can help me with creating path animations a pushpin on the XAML map control

This [article](https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2014/09/25/part-2-bring-your-maps-to-life-creating-animations-with-bing-maps-net/) you provided already taught about creating animations with Maps. But the target version in that article is windows 8.1 with Bing SDK not UWP app, so some APIs cannot be used in UWP app. Such as `LocationCollection()` is replaced by [Geopath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geopath) class, `MapShapeLayer()` maybe replaced by  [MapItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapitemscontrol.aspx) class. More details please reference [Maps and location overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/index) and the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MapControl).

I  convert some of the animations that now they can be used in a UWP app. You can download the demo [here](https://github.com/sunteenwu/PersonalDemo/tree/master/CAnimationMap) for testing.

Comment: so if I am getting it right, the path animations have nothing to do with the Bing map SDK. Also I'll go through the demo shall get back with you on it. One last thing, what about the windows phone 8.1 RT, is there any way to implement map path animations without the use of the Bing SDK or the only way is to use the SDK for winRT?

Comment: @AdityaSharma I just create a blank windows phone 8.1 app and tried the MapControl, it can work. I think you can use MapControl in windows phone 8.1.

Comment: thank you so much. I'll try the solution as soon as I get infront of a machine. If there is anything I'll get back you

Comment: Hi, I checked out the solution. The thing is that the pushpin image blinks while it animates. I was wondering why is that happening? I want to not to blink simply move along the path. could you please help with this

Comment: @AdityaSharma sorry to see this comment late. I also saw the blinks. As I just update the code to met the new version, don't change any features for the code, so I'm not sure what's wrong. I will try to resolve it later, appreciate your patience.

Comment: Great. Please do let me know why is it blinking. I checked, I couldn't find any particular issues. I appreciate your help on this